# Looking for a 3G Modem Manager Software

Tags: networking, wireless, usb-modem, modem, 3g

I have been using Ubuntu during 20+ days. I am now using a 3G wireless modem (huawei e303-h1) to connect with internet. My modem's software is specially designed for Windows. So whenever I connect it in Windows I see a nice GUI which allows me to call, send sms, receive phone calls, monitor network speed and data etc. convenient features. I just want to know if I can install a software on Ubuntu for this modem to do same things that I can do in Windows. Is there any free open source software which can offer me such features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Modem Manager, which can fulfill some of your requirements. It is in Software Center, or can be installed by

```
sudo apt-get install modem-manager-gui
```

It can send, receive SMS, USSD, monitor traffic, networks, etc.

But it can not make phone calls.

Comment: well I see on unity there is a message box which tells 33 new messages but modem manager doesnt show anyone! Also how to call using this?

Comment: If you click on a small triangle close to Incoming folder, does it open? I had this trouble too, and know how to fix it. You can't call with it.

Comment: yes it works! But cant I call anyone using this?

Comment: You also can go to settings and set the behavior to expand folders by default. Regarding making calls, I am afraid it is not possible on Ubuntu.

Comment: There is no settings button/option!

Comment: Also do you know any software which can monitor bandwidth, speed, usage etc.?

Comment: There are options. They are in global menu. Lift cursor up the screen and you will see "Modem Manager GUI". Click it and you will see options.

Comment: And this program can monitor  bandwidth, speed, usage. Press "status", "traffic", "networks", etc.